# How to make CUDA work in Ubuntu so as to enable GPU rendering in Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, linux, luxrender-render-engine

I have installed Blender 2.78c and I would like to make Cycles and LuxRender **render with GPU** on my GeForce GTX 760M. In Windows it works perfectly, but in Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.04 it doesn't allow me to select GPU rendering for Cycles on "user preferences > system" and LuxRender shows me the following error message in the log tab when I select any LuxCore *rendering mode*:

```
OpenCL ERROR: clGetPlatformIDs(-1001)
```

I have already installed NVIDIA drivers, nvidia-cuda-toolkit and nvidia-modprobe from the official repositories, as suggested in other topics, tried to run Blender as root, but **nothing changes**. From the list of installed packages, I get:

> nvidia-375/zesty-updates,zesty-security,now 375.66-0ubuntu0.17.04.1 amd64  [installiert]
>
> nvidia-cuda-dev/zesty,now 8.0.44-3 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
>
> nvidia-cuda-doc/zesty,zesty,now 8.0.44-3 all  [Installiert,automatisch]
>
> nvidia-cuda-gdb/zesty,now 8.0.44-3 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
>
> nvidia-cuda-toolkit/zesty,now 8.0.44-3 amd64  [installiert]
>
> nvidia-modprobe/zesty,now 375.26-1 amd64  [installiert]
>
> nvidia-opencl-dev/zesty,now 8.0.44-3 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
>
> nvidia-opencl-icd-375/zesty-updates,zesty-security,now 375.66-0ubuntu0.17.04.1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
>
> nvidia-prime/zesty,now 0.8.4 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
>
> nvidia-profiler/zesty,now 8.0.44-3 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
>
> nvidia-settings/zesty,now 381.22-0ubuntu0~gpu17.04.1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
>
> nvidia-visual-profiler/zesty,now 8.0.44-3 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]

What should I do? Why does it work in the Windows installation and not in Ubuntu?

Comment: I have the same problem but with OpenCL (I have an AMD GPU). Even if I DRI_PRIME=1 and run Blender, or right click blender in GNOME 3 and choose Use Dedicated Graphics Card it still doesn't appear in preferences>system

Answer (score 6):

### After long trying I could solve this problem

I found out that my NVIDIA card was not being recognized by the NVIDIA driver I had installed. So NVIDIA X server settings was "empty" like in this thread: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2342538 but it was recognized by Ubuntu, what I could see by entering the command `lspci -nn | grep '\[03'` in terminal and getting PCI info about the "3D Controller".

But if I ran `prime-select query` in terminal I was getting `unknown`. My Laptop has a NVIDIA and an Intel card and I thought NVIDIA was working because I had graphical acceleration, but I think it was the whole time using the Intel controller. Tried to change the output by typing `sudo prime-select nvidia` and then I got `nvidia` by checking prime-select again. But if I restarted the system it was again `unknown` and nvidia-settings remained empty. I followed all helps I found in forums or stackexchange posts and my problem wasn't solved.

The solution that worked for me was uninstalling NVIDIA drives completely (did this several times) and installing nvidia drivers in a specific order:
First **Ctrl+Alt+F1** to enter the tty and then:

```
sudo service lightdm stop # to kill the user interface process
sudo apt purge nvidia-* # to remove all nvidia packages
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia # check that no nvidia packages remain
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa # if you still didn't add it
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-375 # installed the NVIDIA drivers v.375.66
sudo apt install nvidia-prime nvidia-settings # Probably already installed
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit # if you want to use CUDA
sudo apt install nvidia-modprobe
```

when restarting I disabled IEFI secure boot in the secure boot blue screen. After doing everything the NVIDIA card was not recognized yet. So I went to the tab "additional drivers" on the `software-properties-gtk` (just type this in terminal to open) and **selected the driver Nvidia version 340.102 (proprietary)** and clicked apply changes. After rebooting the machine again the card was recognized by NVIDIA X server settings (or `nvidia-settings`) and everything worked fine, Blender recognized CUDA and so on. I just don't understand why NVIDIA put my GeForce GTX 760M in the list of supported cards for the drivers version 340, 375 and so on, but actually just one (or some) of them works, in my case this (older?) version nvidia-340. I had already tried to install nvidia-340 directly from the repository and also select it in additional drivers without previous installation. It should have worked, but it hasn't.

**Conclusions:** the nvidia drivers for Linux are there, but it's a huge mess! Ubuntu does its job fine by recognizing it with the command List PCI `lspci`, but the nvidia support is messy and unclear with this several versions. So, if you still have problems on making your card work, **try** to install **different propietary driver versions** or select them from the additional drivers list. Maybe the driver you tried to use is actually not the one that works with your graphics card. Let's see if NVIDIA decides to make that better and start to *opensource* their drivers!

Comment: This was in the right track for me but packages were still installed so I removed them manually using  sudo dpkg --force-all -P <package> like here: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1031351/cannot-purge-and-install-nvidia-driver/

Answer (score 5):

I found the same problems a few days ago, in my case the solution was to install the nvidia-cuda-toolkit pakage.

sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

Answer (score 1):

For CUDA to work, add the blender user(s) to the 'video' group through:

sudo adduser  video

It is may also be useful to install the nvidia-modprobe package (which is not a dependency because it depends on your hardware).

link : https://launchpad.net/~thomas-schiex/+archive/ubuntu/blender

Comment: wow great repo for ubuntu blender ! with this everything is working now !
Another great repo https://lambdalabs.com/lambda-stack-deep-learning-software 
it install cuda cudnn and nvida drivers in 2 clicks

Answer (score 0):

"The nvidia drivers for Linux are there, but it's a huge mess!"

I wholeheartedly agree :P

Your solution was very technical. For my mere needs I've managed to reproduce a good method for having GPU always available for Blender in Ubuntu and Ubuntu-based distros. I wrote an article about it here:

**[Installing NVIDIA Drivers in Linux](https://medium.com/@manujarvinen/installing-nvidia-drivers-in-linux-7454f82ef5b)**

Answer (score 0):

For blender newbies running into this problem, the issue might be that you haven't enabled CUDA in the settings. It is disabled by default.

`Edit > Preferences > System > Cycles render devices` and choose `CUDA`.
Then, in the view port, switch out eevee for cycles.
That did it for me.

If you're on linux, test if the command `nvidia-smi` outputs your current GPU details and usage statistics. If `nvidia-smi` does not work, nothing CUDA related will.